# ¿Como calcular el numero de meses entre dos fechas?

Tags: python, pandas, date

tengo el siguiente problema: necesito calcular el numero de meses entre dos fechas pero al momento de correr el codigo me contabiliza el numero de dias, Ayuda por favor

mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

F_inicio = pd.to_datetime( input('Teclear fecha inicial: '),format= "%d/%m/%Y")
F_final = pd.to_datetime(input('Teclear fecha final: '),format= "%d/%m/%Y") 

def diff_month(d1, d2):
    return (d1.year - d2.year) * 12 + d1.month - d2.month
print(diff_month(F_final-F_inicio))
```

Comment: Buen día, el código me funciona bien pero cometiste un error en la última linea, estas usando el signo `-` pero la función recibe 2 parámetros separado por `,`. Pon `print(diff_month(F_final,F_inicio))` y debe funcionar

Comment: Tu codigo, tal como lo muestras, deberia decirte que te olvidaste de pasarle un argumento a diff_fechas, pues le pasas un solo argumento, y es un objeto timedelta quw representa la diferencia entre dos fechas.

Comment: No necesitas de pandas para convertir el input a un formato datetetime, puedes hacerlo con `strptime`

Answer (score 1):

El error del código es que estás llamando a `diff_month()` con solo un argumento (la diferencia entre dos fechas) en lugar de llamarla con dos (fecha inicio y termino).

Tampoco necesitas pandas; puedes usar `datetime.strptime()` que recibe un string y un formato, y genera un datetime acorde.

#### Solución

```
from datetime import datetime

def diff_month(d1, d2):
    return (d1.year - d2.year) * 12 + d1.month - d2.month

inicio = input('Teclear fecha inicial (dd/mm/yyyy): ')
final = input('Teclear fecha final (dd/mm/yyyy): ')

F_inicio = datetime.strptime(inicio, "%d/%m/%Y")
F_final = datetime.strptime(final, "%d/%m/%Y")

print(diff_month(F_final, F_inicio))
```

produce:

```
Teclear fecha inicial (dd/mm/yyyy): 1/2/2022
Teclear fecha final (dd/mm/yyyy): 20/10/2022
8

Process finished with exit code 0
```